# Class library lib and dll files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

To use class library I must have header file and lib file that I suppose contains compiled library code. So, why and when I need dll file? I have breath understanding that in case of dynamic linking I must use dll and in case of static linking there is no need to use dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a library project or a DLL project. A DLL is good if it will be used by multiple exes. A lib is good if you want it to become part of an exe.

DLL projects generate both a DLL file and a lib file. The import lib file is very small and just contains a jump table so the exe can be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

When your library is dynamic library i.e, `.dll`, `.lib` file have exports table. `.h` header file have function prototype.

Export table is table of all exported functions from dll.